# How to get both Open and Closed projects in Rally using Java api

Tags: rest, rally, java

I've used the following QueryFilter to get the List of projects, but it never displays Closed projects only Open projects

```
 projectRequest.setQueryFilter((new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "DT-").or(new     QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "UX-")).or(new QueryFilter("Name", "contains", "RT-")).or(new QueryFilter("State", "=", "Closed")))
```

I even added

```
  .or(new QueryFilter("State", "=", "Open"))
```

But the result didn't change?

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS API does not return closed projects by design. There was a performance optimization made a couple of years ago that limited queries to open projects.